# Converting mp3 to caf file for iPhone

Tags: iphone, audio, mp3, core-audio, caf

I am experimenting with the sampling rate of the mp3 file to convert it into caf format. 
afconvert -f caff -d LEI16@44100 ./fricatives_play_all.mp3 ./test.caf
 afconvert -f caff -d LEI16@22100 ./fricatives_play_all.mp3 ./test.caf
 afconvert -f caff -d LEI16@12000 ./fricatives_play_all.mp3 ./test.caf
 afconvert -f caff -d LEI16@20100 ./fricatives_play_all.mp3 ./test.caf
 afconvert -f caff -d LEI16@15100 ./fricatives_play_all.mp3 ./test.caf
 afconvert -f caff -d LEI16@14100 ./fricatives_play_all.mp3 ./test.caf
 afconvert -f caff -d LEI16@13100 ./fricatives_play_all.mp3 ./test.caf
 afconvert -f caff -d LEI16@44100 -c 1 ./fricatives_play_all.mp3 ./test.caf
 afconvert -f caff -d LEI16@13100 -c 1 ./fricatives_play_all.mp3 ./test.caf
 afconvert -f caff -d LEI16@22100 -c 1 ./test ./test2.caf

I have used different sampling rates as above for converting mp3 files
to caf files. For instance, for a 38.5 MB file :

Sampling Rate       Size
15,100                   72.6 MB
14,100                   67.8 MB
13,100                   63 MB

As you can see the file size reduces with the lower sampling rate but
the quality gradually decreases. If you could provide more insight
into this problem, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: What is the question exactly? Are you asking why sound quality is proportional to the sampling rate?

Comment: Is there a way to lower the size of the caf file without affecting the quality?

Comment: @bpararj: no, there is no way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a stereo file, you could convert it to mono. You can also use the IMA-4:1 compression, which reduces the file size to 25%, but it does reduce the quality somewhat.